put many line plots on the same row
I have made 5 line plots a, b, c, e, f. I want to combine them into one plot and put all of them in one row. I used wrap_elements and I don't know how to adjust the number of plots in each row.
abcef <- a + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50")) +
  b + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50")) +
  c + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50")) +
  e + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50")) +
  f + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50"))

wrap_elements(panel = abcef) +
  labs(tag = "Year") +
  theme(
    plot.tag = element_text(size = rel(1)),
    plot.tag.position = "bottom"
  )



You seem to use the patchwork package , as suggested by the presence of patchwork::wrap_elements(). Are they real ggplot? you could use patchwork::plot_layout(nrow = 1, byrow = FALSE) in that case  (see https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/patchwork.html#controlling-layout)
